# Disable initial zoom when viewing a page with mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, zooming

Is there a possbility to disable the initial zoom you get when viewing a page with your smartphone?

I don't want to disable zoom, I'd just like the user to view the entire page (=> width) when loading it and not just a small rectangle.

I've tried several solutions suggested by others but none of them worked for me.

Comment: To avoid people suggesting things you have already tried, can you say what you tried and didn't work?

Comment: @DaveRead I don't remember them all, but they were many. Just watch the answers below as I don't expect most of them to be working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay well that was easy. I slightly tweaked a solution I found from Google. Here's the only code that worked for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=960; user-scalable=yes;" />
```

It sets the default zoom to 960px (change to the width of your page) and still allows the user to zoom in/out.

EDIT: **It looks like it allows zoom on the default Internet Browser (SGS4) but it disables zoom when using Google Chrome.**

Comment: Works like a charm on SGS3 Chrome,Internet and Boat. Works great on Safari iPhone 5 too

Answer (score 3):

Try add this to the `head` of your document:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes", target-densitydpi=device-dpi />`

Where `initial-scale` is how much you want it to be initially, `maximum-scale` is how much the user is able to zoom, and `user-scalable` is whether or not they are allowed to zoom.

**The** `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` **is needed for mobile devices with a high dpi (or resolution) such as the Samsung Galaxy S4** but it is added to the end of the meta because devices such as the iPhone does not recognize it.

I haven't tested this myself on an SGS4 because I do not own one but if you want to be specific on the initial-scale of the device, can try adding `media="(device-width: 480px) and (device-height: 800px)"` after `user-scalable` where `480px` is the viewport width of the SGS4 and the `800px` is the viewport height of a SGS4.
So it should look like: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes", media="(device-width: 480px) and (device-height: 800px)", target-densitydpi=device-dpi />`

Comment: Sadly it does not work, even with the added code for high dpi.

Comment: Is your CSS fluid as in the container elements use `width: 100%`? Also try to lower the `initial-scale` to something lower such as `intial-scale=0.8` or something

Comment: the html/body has min-width: 960px; and width: 100%;

Comment: Did you try to lower the initial-scale to something lower such as `intial-scale=0.8` or something?

Comment: When I change initial-scale to 0.4 then it's a perfect solution, but I fear this solution will look different on different devices.

I will load the page with some of my other devices and report back!

Comment: Okay, bad timing, looks like my old smartphone just died. I will report back as soon as I have tested it on other smartphones.

Comment: See my updated answer on how to do viewports for specific device sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Read up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Does not work on SGS4 Google Chrome / default Internet Browser.