# How to disable mobile view of "Airtable" on my website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, airtable

I'm building a website using wordpress.
On the site, I embled an "Airtable".

```
<iframe style="background: transparent; border: 1px solid #ccc;" src="https://airtable.com/embed/shr4DVQq5GWJEG4xV?backgroundColor=gray&amp;layout=card&amp;viewControls=on" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is the embled code.
This works good viewing with a pc, but some important functions is not available on the mobile phone mode. What I dreadfully need is to disable the mobile mode even if the viewer is using a mobile device.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

Put this one of them in head tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Or this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=960; user-scalable=yes;" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!
Can I ask where should I put the code in?
I'm sorry I just started to write javascripts yesterday.

Comment: @Takuan put this code in head tags, here is more information about soultion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821639/disable-initial-zoom-when-viewing-a-page-with-mobile

Comment: Thank you very much to helping me. I tried all you have taught me. It "worked" as the web site became pc view or decreased in size but the airtable's view is always moblie mode :(. I tried the code below to make the media itself smaller. It became smaller, but the airtable was still mobile mode.

Comment: <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;"><iframe style="transform: scale(0.5); -o-transform: scale(0.5); -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); -moz-transform: scale(0.5); -ms-transform: scale(0.5); transform-origin: 0 0; -o-transform-origin: 0 0; -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;" src="https://airtable.com/embed/shr4DVQq5GWJEG4xV?backgroundColor=gray&amp;layout=card&amp;viewControls=on" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>

Comment: I'm still figuring it out.
I'm not sure but I think the application recognize the device itself. What can I do if I add some code in the embled code which I mentioned at first?